# Setting Up Owasp crs rules Error creating rule: Failed to resolve operator: detectXSS on line 56

Tags: security, xss, owasp, apache2.4, mod-security2

After adding Owasp crs rules for Modsecurity and restarting apache I am getting this error in REQUEST-941-APPLICATION-ATTACK-XSS.conf file.

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 56 of /etc/apache2/modsecurity.d/rules/REQUEST-941-APPLICATION-ATTACK-XSS.conf:
Error creating rule: Failed to resolve operator: detectXSS
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Please help me to fix this issue

Answer (score 1):

DetectXSS was only added in ModSecurity 2.8: https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#detectXSS

You must be running a previous version. Possibly because you are using a packaged version and they are terrible about keeping these up to date [except for security patches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41050346/centos-7-get-latest-apache-package/). Centos/RHEL for example only has ModSecurity 2.7.3 in the standard repo for example.

You should upgrade to the latest version.